# Android getDrawable exception in Edittext

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my XML. After write something in `EditText` and click it have Exception. I have test it on emulator API21 and real device API19 too. I cant find my package in the stacktrace exception.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:theme="@style/BlackTextViewStyle"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/contactText"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contactForm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:lines="10"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        style="?android:buttonBarStyle">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendContactsButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textSize="@dimen/main_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is exception

```
02-11 14:31:23.880  19023-19648/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.opentaxi.android, PID: 19023
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
            at android.support.v7.widget.bb.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:133)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:3797)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:3776)
            at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:1632)
            at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7995)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
            at android.support.v7.view.m.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.view.m.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePo
```

Comment: Could you post the code executed on click?

Comment: I dont have on click over EditText code. The only click event its have sendContactsButton @Click void sendContactsButton() -> I have use AA framework. But Exception appears if I click on EditText only after I write something in this multiline EditText field

Comment: Click on the sendContactsButton button works. Click on EditText without to write some letter do not cause Exeption. The problem appears is only if I write something and click on EditText instead on Button.

Comment: If I write something in Edit delete it and then click its have no Exception. It appears like Android bug. Maybe it is from multiLine options.

Answer (score 0):

Its have `android:theme="@style/BlackTextViewStyle"` in LinearLayout after remove theme and add color to TextView its works now. But with this theme not works:

```
<style name="BlackTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_color</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```